# Random "No compiler provided" error Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I try to build project using maven. And everytime I can have accidentally received error

```
No compiler is provided in this environment. perhaps you are running on a jre rather than a jdk?
```

And than I can run build again and everything is ok.

```
    JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40
M2_HOME C:\Program Files\Maven

D:\java_projects>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T23:58:10+03:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven
Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
D:\java_projects>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.epam</groupId>
    <artifactId>News</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <tiles.version>3.0.5</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
            <artifactId>unitils-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have this error in 90% of using cmd(mvn package) and about 40% of using Eclipse (Maven build)

**SOLVED:**

Download latest JDK, update JAVA_HOME, Update `Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs`

Comment: Anyway, you should try using a JDK instead of a JRE

Comment: If you want to build on a JRE instead of a JDK you need your pom file to specify a compiler.  The Eclipse compiler is available from Maven Central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You running it on the `jre` as the error says , choose your jdk path.

> Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->jre1.8.0_40

You should have an entry with a JDK there. If not point it to JDK.

Then,

> RightClick Project -> Maven -> Update Project

Comment: I did it 1 million times, but it error occurs again and again

Comment: @VyacheslavTsivina Have you pointed it to the `JDK` path ?

Comment: thank you. New JDK solved my problem. Such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Install a JDK and set the `JAVA-HOME` to your jdk path.